# Anchor tags jumping in Chrome because of URL?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, anchor

Anchor tags causing a jump: In chrome, not firefox (works fine in firefox), when going from my 'work' page to my contact anchor then clicking about, the anchor jumps to my about then immediately back to the contact anchor. I think it has something to do with my url ending in #gocontact. Having trouble finding the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var tOffset = $(target).offset().top
        var offAmt;

        //determine the amt of padding needs to be offset on scrollTop
        if( target == '#goContact'){
            offAmt = 90;
        }else if( target == '#goAbout'){
            offAmt = 120;
        }else{
            offAmt = 0;
        }//end else

        //smooth scrolling
        $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: tOffset - offAmt},900, 'swing');
    });
}); 

$(document).scroll(function(){

    console.log( 'scrolltop', $(document).scrollTop() );

    var scrolltop = $(document).scrollTop();

    //get bottom of screen
    var scrollheight = scrolltop + $(window).height();
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem e.preventDefault(); works on all browsers except Google Chrome (I'm running Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit)).

Comment: Even this fiddle isn't working for me in chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/3ASpX/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to recreate the issue in chrome.  I clicked 'work', then 'contact', then 'about' and everything scrolls to the correct position from what I'm seeing.

There is a touch of lag as the screen scrolls to either the top or bottom (about/contact sections) the first time around due to the lazy loaded hexagon images in the middle of the screen but other than that everything seems to go to where it should.

A couple suggestions would be to clear out your cache (maybe you're seeing the result of some old js that isn't updated) also you could change the == in 
(target == "whatever") into (target === "whatever") using triple equals for more of a precise check.

Comment: thanks for the response, I had a friend try to and not getting the error. On my machine I clear the cache every time. Going from work to either about or contact then the anchors on that page keeps jumping